# Downloading google street view panoramas programmatically from a URL request

Tags: c++, node.js, google-street-view, unreal-engine4

I'm currently trying to download the equirectangular images Google displays in their 360 view of Google street view to an image file so that I may display them in VR in Unreal Engine 4. I've tried a few things -

Requesting the panorama tiles from a constructed URL [in the format described in the Street View API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-custom-simple). This ends up returning a file-not-found error for any pano ID that isn't the example one outlined. Perhaps I'm using the wrong method of getting a panorama ID? I used the [following example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata) to extract the pano ID and plugged that into the URL with tileX = tileY = 0 and Zoom level of 1 to no avail.

I've also tried [downloading separate 2D images taken at 90-degree angles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro#size) but when I go to display them on the inside of a cube, the images are misaligned.

There's a tool called [UnrealJS](https://github.com/ncsoft/Unreal.js-core) that I've been looking into in order to grab the panorama data and save it off, but my inexperience with Node.js and server-side JS has made this a very confusing, fruitless endeavor. Other programs I've looked into that allow you to extract these panoramic images use canvas tags to request the maps API and then save what Google's API writes to the canvas into a buffer. Is this the way to go? UnrealJS does support a bastardized version of HTML that I may be able to use - this, however, is less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Streetview panoramas are divided into an equal grid from an equirectangular image. [This article](http://www.newtonscannon.com/2014/01/26/capturing-spherical-scenes-from-google-streetview/) explains how to get the url of every tile. For zoom level 5 (the highest resolution) there are 26 by 13 tiles (each tile being 512x512). All that is left is to download every image and draw each one onto a large empty image to their respective place using their position on the grid.

**Note: by doing this you will be breaking Google's terms of service**